# Не работают Яндекс Карты

Tags: карты, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

Делал все по этой документации:
https://tech.yandex.ru/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/android/quickstart-docpage/

Но все равно, вместо карт сплошная сетка, не понимаю в чем причина.
Кто с этим сталкивался подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить.

Comment: Такое бывает, если используется неправильный или неактивный ключ.

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается я всё правильно делал. Кто бы знал, что у Яндекса активация ключа длится целых два дня!